# Bot Framework Emulator v4.0: Simulate group and multiple users

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I was wondering if there was a way to create fake groups and/or different users with the Bot Framework Emulator v4.0 as I would like to test my bot on different scenarios.

For example I would like my bot to be able to selectively target individual users with proactive messages and other things like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple endpoints and open them in a separate tabs. Each endpoint will use separate ChannelAccountId, so it should be possible to test selective proactive messages.